# Convert NSString into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am trying to convert (or copy?) a NSString into a NSMutableArray. I guess my problem is that I don't really understand the structure of a MutableArray. In my limited knowledge, an Array could look like this:

```
NoteBook = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int temp = 0; temp < 3; temp++) {
    [NoteBook insertObject:@"Page" atIndex:temp];
}
```

Which would give me an Array of **PagePagePage**. Let's assume I wanted to open a txt file which contains PagePagePage, but the words were separated by a defined string so that I can keep the individual objects in my array apart, like so: **Page--- end of page ---Page--- end of page ---Page**.

Now, my next step would be to read this information from the txt file:

```
NSString *tempTextOut = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                    error:&error];
NoteBook = [tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n--- end of page ---\n"];
```

However, the last line does not work and I'm told by xCode: Incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct NSArray*', expected 'struct NSMutableArray*'. I don't really understand this - NSArray and MutableArray should be compatible (as one is the subclass of the other). Shouldn't xCode tell me that the problem is that I've been trying to convert a NSString into an NSMutableArray?

Would I perhaps need to re-set my MutableArray before putting something back into it, because right now, it still contains **PagePagePage** which I have assigned to it in the first step. I thought my NoteBook mutable array would simply be replaced by the string, but I guess that won't be the case.

I'd very much appreciate any help in this matter. Thanks!

Comment: [Convert NSString separated by comma to NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8204215/194544)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning a mutable object to the same immutable type will lead to runtime errors if you want to manipulate the immutable instance.

You can get your mutable copy by calling:

```
NoteBook = [[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n--- end of page ---\n"] mutableCopy];
```

If NoteBook is a retained property you should assign to it this way:

```
self.NoteBook = [[[tempTextOut componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n--- end of page ---\n"] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

so the mutable copy doesn't get over retained. You can release in your dealloc method then as normal.

Comment: Note that you're then responsible for releasing `NoteBook` eventually, as it's not going to be autoreleased like the original array.

Comment: Yes, you claim ownership by calling mutableCopy.

Comment: @Noah Witherspoon: Thanks! I've already have it released in my dealloc method at the very end of the program, but it was there before as I did the alloc init thing at the very beginning for NoteBook. Are you therefore saying that I need to release it somewhere else as well? Or will it suffice to release it in my dealloc? I guess you didn't mean the tempTextOut as this will be autoreleased, right?

Comment: Thanks, that explains it beautifully! I think this is the first time I understood what getting over retained means. Thanks so much for this illuminating moment!

Answer (score 4):

`componentsSeparatedByString:` returns a plain immutable NSArray, not an NSMutableArray. You can pass the array to `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]` or use `mutableCopy` on the array to get a mutable array from it, or you can use `addObjectsFromArray:` on an existing NSMutableArray to add objects to it.

If you go the `mutableCopy` route, do remember that you are responsible for calling `release` or `autorelease` on it.