# Convert NSString separated by comma to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert NSArray to NSString in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828665/convert-nsarray-to-nsstring-in-objective-c)

I have an array of an NSArray myArray, here is the content:

```
 (
            "<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7dd0> 8671085923283003246",
            "<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e50> 16275751483823231324",
            "<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e70> 4976771456698615367"
 )
```

I used the code below to assign to an NSString myString:

```
NSString *myString = [myArray description];
```

And the out put is still as expected:

```
 (
            "<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7dd0> 8671085923283003246",
            "<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e50> 16275751483823231324",
            "<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e70> 4976771456698615367"
 )
```

Now, say I want to convert myString back to an array named newArray, I used this:

```
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
newArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

But the content of the newArray is now different:

```
(       
"(
    \"<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7dd0> 8671085923283003246\"",
        "
    \"<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e50> 16275751483823231324\"",
        "
    \"<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e70> 4976771456698615367\""
)"
)
```

Any idea what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Note that the description also features the newline characters and brackets, not just commas.

Comment: Try to store mediapickeritem using core data as unstrung.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are two methods

- [- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:)
- [- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString:)

Use

```
NSString *myString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]; //instead of [myArray description];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what the NSArray prints out.

```
"(
\"<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7dd0> 8671085923283003246\"",
    "
\"<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e50> 16275751483823231324\"",
    "
\"<MPConcreteMediaItem: 0x1b7e70> 4976771456698615367\""
)"
```

To print out the individual elements in the array try this and see what happens

```
NSString *myString1 = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *myString2 = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(myString1);
NSLog(myString2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something but you are doing operations on "C" strings not NSStrings. You need more "@"s.

Comment: I am assuming this is not raw code but the output form an `NSLog()` therefore it will not have the `@`'s