# How to use API in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create iOS app, which will show me an actual temperature from my API. I created API, which shows me, which IDs of sensors are available in this format:

```
1;2;100
```

It's means, I have 3 sensors with ID 1, 2 and 100...
When I have this I can get actual temperature from api, using this string
    http://someurl.com/api/actual/ID
when ID is an ID of sensor which I want...
It gives me this:

```
Name_of_sensor;02/26/2015;21:16;22.88
```

When:
- Name of sensor is name of sensor of course
- 02/26/2015 is a date when was this temperature captured
- 21:16 is a time when was this temperature captured
- 22.88 is actual temp in C

How to use the first string to get available IDs and after that get values of all sensors and take it in the variables?
For example:
variables for ID 1 could be name1, date1, time1 and value1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the result in this format only i,e

```
Name_of_sensor;02/26/2015;21:16;22.88
```

and the last part always will have the temperature, then write this

```
NSString *fromAPI = @"Name_of_sensor;02/26/2015;21:16;22.88";
NSArray *breakingString = [fromAPI componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];    
NSString *temperature = [breakingString objectAtIndex:[breakingString count]-1];
NSLog(@"%@",temperature);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you say me please, how to get value of *fromAPI from my API using this string: http://someurl.com/api/actual/1 ?

Comment: well that depends on how the structure of the JSON/XML is from your webservice that you are getting, Cast it into a dictionary and traverse the dictionary with the appropriate key and u will get this value.

Answer (score 0):

First if you don't have particular need to use the format specified above(i.e. Name_of_sensor;02/26/2015;21:16;22.88), you should consider using JSON. JSON is very popular data exchange format specially in Server-Client case.

Your JSON should look something like:

```
{
    "sensors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "date": "02/01/2015",
            "temp": 12.5
        }
    ]
}
```

[JSON Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/json/)

[JSON with iOS Objective-C Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

Otherwise you can separate components on ','. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204215/3332383)

Answer (score 0):

As Taha  says you should look at `JSON` however if you require the structure you are using for your API then you should split the string based on the `;`

Assuming your API returns a string that you store as an `NSString` called `string_from_api`

```
NSArray *dataArray = [string_from_api componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];
NSString *firstID = [dataArray objectAtIndex: 0];
```

You could also use a for loop to get all of the data out and process it

```
NSArray *dataArray = [string_from_api componentsSeparatedByString: @";"];

for(int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++)
{
    NSString *thisID = [dataArray objectAtIndex: 0];
    //Then call the function you have created that gets the temperature, passing the ID
    [self function_to_get_temperature:firstID];
}
```